# Vim- Change background color of certain portion of code

Tags: vim

I usually spend a lot of time tinkering with existing code. I need to focus on only a small portion of the file, for which I would like to grey out the background for the rest of the file, so that the portion that I'm interested in stands out distinctively. This should increase my productivity immensely. Does anyone know how can I change background for only certain part of the file?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but maybe a helpful tip to increase productivity: The Vim plugin [mark.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1238) allows to highlight several words (variables, functions, etc...) in different colors. See [here](http://www.habermann-net.de/public/development/gvimMarkExample.gif) for an example. This helps to see at a glance where variables, functions etc. are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the limelight plugin for Vim. This Plugin Highlights the current code block and dimme the other code before and afterwards.

You can find it here:

https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim

Answer (score 4):

Try my [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin. That opens a selected part of the code in a new window. Whenever you write your changes, the will be taken back to the original buffer.

You could of course use syntax highlighting or even the sign column (my [BackgroundColor](https://github.com/chrisbra/BackgroundColor.vim) plugin does this) to distinct highlight a certain region, but this will be awkward and will get out of sync soon if you add lines or remove lines.